# What should be the initial hole size?

Tags: geometry

I have two plates of triangle shape. Lets call it A and B. [plate with hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dylyn.png)

The plate has a quarter circle hole of radius 16mm at the bottom. Now when the plate is placed on the flat floor and looked from above the hole size will be 16mm radius.

Now I will move the plates downward by 45 degree and look again from the top. The size of hole would have reduced, right?

Now my question is I want the hole to be of 16mm radius even after bending by 45 deg then what should be the initial radius of the hole such that after bending I get 16mm hole, when looked from top.

I know it has to be something greater than 16mm but I dont know how to calculate it. Please help me calculate the initial hole size such that after placing the plates at an angle of 45deg I get 16mm radius hole when looked from above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d$ be the apparent diameter of a hole (for example, the diameter of the pipe that needs to go through the hole), $w$ the larger, actual diameter of the hole, and $\varphi$ the tilt angle (with $\varphi=0°$ meaning no tilt, that the surface and the hole are perpendicular, so $w = d$), then we have a right triangle (completely unrelated to the shape of OP's pipes!), where $$\frac{d}{w} = \cos\varphi$$
This means that $$w = \frac{d}{\cos\varphi} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$

In particular,
$$\text{if } \varphi=45° \text{ then } w = \frac{d}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} = d \sqrt{2} \approx 1.4142 \, d$$

Note that the hole needed is not round: it is an ellipse, with major diameter $w$, and minor diameter $d$. If you draw such an ellipse on a piece of paper or cardboard, and tilt it by $\varphi$ from perpendicular to your eye direction, you'll see that the ellipse will look perfectly circular. (The larger diameter is in the direction of the tilt, and the smaller diameter perpendicular to that.)